# C++::vector of vector in `struct` as data type of another vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am working on a physics engine related project. In the C++ code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Vector3
{
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
};

struct object
{
  std::vector < std::vector < Vector3 > > set_vertices;
  int ID;
  int Type;
};

class World
{
  public:
    std::vector< object > objects;

  private:
    // other members
};

int main (void)
{
  World world;

  // How to fill in "objects" of "world"?
  //   Is this safe to do?
  world.objects.resize(5);
  //   What about the way of allocating "set_vertices" below?
  for(size_t i=0; i<world.objects.size(); i++)
  {
    world.objects[i].set_vertices.resize(12, std::vector < Vector3 >(3));
    for(size_t j=0; j<world.objects[i].set_vertices.size(); j++)
    {
      for(size_t k=0; k<world.objects[i].set_vertices[j].size(); k++)
      {
        world.objects[i].set_vertices[j][k].x = 0.0f;
        world.objects[i].set_vertices[j][k].y = 0.0f;
        world.objects[i].set_vertices[j][k].z = 0.0f;
        world.objects[i].ID = i;
        world.objects[i].Type = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

is the way I have allocated memory for `objects` of `world` safe? There would be any memory related issue? Is there any better way of initializing `objects` dynamically (i.e. not in constructor)? If so, how? thanks.

Comment: seems perfectly fine to me. There are of course questions of efficiency: using std::vectors in other vectors means you are copying the vectors a lot, it would probably be better to use smart pointers

Comment: in C++11 that is mostly a non-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine that using RAII and having the constructor and destructor of `object` to take care of the memory would be a better way of doing this.

Adding in a new `object` into world you can make use of `std::vector` ability to resize dynamically by just calling `push_back()` instead of needing to create the loop that has `i` as the index. To avoid unnecessary resizes if you know how many elements you are adding in advance you can call `.reserve(n)` where `n` is the number of elements you are adding.

Comment: It's already mostly RAII. No extra handling in a destructor required. But moving the dimension-specific initialisation to a constructor would finish the job yes

Comment: He's done the loop to save expansions. But your suggestion plus `.reserve` would have the same effect. Six of one...

Comment: Yeah I see that what he's doing will have the same effect, I just subjectively think the code looks cleaner doing it the other way.

Comment: @Rasoul: RAII is a key c++ idiom known that lets you use constructors and destructors to manage memory more conveniently. See the wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Comment: @shuttle87: I'd agree with that. BTW please use notification syntax so that I am notified about your reply.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe.

You could save boilerplate by moving all that filling into a constructor, if appropriate.

You might also be able to find a more efficient approach than levels of nested vectors.

So, it's safe but could still be improved.